# str.match not working when trying to break a string into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to create a variable out of the text from a html element which is this

`<div id="topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents" style="height:auto;"><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Gasp for supprise</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Giggle</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Say hello</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Come on</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Kick somebody out</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Kiss somebody</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Scream</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Yawn for sleepy</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Snoring</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div></div>`

I declare the variable like this

```
var elt = document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents");
var lists = elt.textContent;
```

and I am expecting something like this:

```
Gasp for surprise    Giggle    Say hello    Come on    Kick somebody out    Kiss somebody    Scream    Yawn for sleepy    Snoring
```

`console.log(lists);` shows exactly that which means no problem, right?

Now I need to convert all that into an array that looks like this:

```
var sounds = {
  "gasp" : {
    url : "gasp.mp3",
  },
  "giggle" : {
    url : "giggle.mp3",
  },
[...]
  "scream" : {
    url : "scream.mp3",
  },
  "snoring" : {
    url : "snoring.mp3",
  }
};
```

So I use the code below:

```
var lists = elt.textContent;
const sounds = lists.toLowerCase().split('    ').reduce((accum, str) => {
                const name = str.match(/^([^ ]+)/)[0];
                accum[name] = { url: '/../flashsound/' + name + '.mp3' };
                return accum;
              }, {});
```

It's not working for some reason. I get an error that says str.match is empty. I checked with `console.log(sounds);` and nothing shows. What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `textContent` does not return the string you listed:

```
'Gasp for surprise    Giggle    Say hello    Come on    Kick somebody out    Kiss somebody    Scream    Yawn for sleepy    Snoring'
```

It actually returns a string with some additional padding:

```
'  Gasp for supprise    Giggle    Say hello    Come on    Kick somebody out    Kiss somebody    Scream    Yawn for sleepy    Snoring   ';
```

```js
var elt = document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents");
var lists = elt.textContent;
console.log(`"${lists}"`);
```

```html
<div id="topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents" style="height:auto;"><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Gasp for supprise</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Giggle</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Say hello</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Come on</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Kick somebody out</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Kiss somebody</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Scream</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Yawn for sleepy</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Snoring</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div></div>
```

So, when the first iteration of the `reduce` runs, it tries to match the first string:

```
'  gasp for supprise'
```

against

```
/^([^ ]+)/
```

In ordinary language: the beginning of the string, followed by 1 or more non-space characters. But the string *starts* with spaces, so the regex fails.

To fix it, `trim()` the `textContent` first:

```
var lists = elt.textContent.trim();
```

But there's another problem: your current code turns the URLs into something like this:

```
"url": "/../flashsound/gasp.mp3"
```

but you say you want

```
url : "gasp.mp3",
```

so, remove the beginning `/../flashsound/` when setting the URL:

```js
const elt = document.getElementById("topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents");
const lists = elt.textContent.trim();
const sounds = lists.toLowerCase().split('    ').reduce((accum, str) => {
  const name = str.match(/^([^ ]+)/)[0];
  accum[name] = {
    url: name + '.mp3'
  };
  return accum;
}, {});
console.log(sounds);
```

```html
<div id="topcmm-123flashchat-sound-messages-contents" style="height:auto;"><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Gasp for supprise</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Giggle</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Say hello</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Come on</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Kick somebody out</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Kiss somebody</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Scream</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Yawn for sleepy</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div><div class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block" onmouseover="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block-over'" onmouseout="this.className='topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-singe-bar-block'"> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-text">Snoring</span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-test-icon"></span> <span class="topcmm-123flashchat-light-color-panel-sound-sent-icon"></span> </div></div>
```

Comment: sorry, I messed up. `/../flashsound/` should be there. I keep forgetting to put it back.